# How to receive a iterator pair in a method?

Tags: c++, stl

How can I receive a iterator pair in my own function/method?

```
void moveMessages(const std::InputIterator<uint64_t> begin, const std::InputIterator<uint64_t> end, uint32_t to_folder_id, int32_t from_folder=-1);
```

Im trying like this, bug gcc dont like it.. Probably i am missing something important..

I found somewhere a **template** version to do this. It is possible to do this without templates? Probably its enogh to receive an "input iterator base class" as a parameter, but how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found somewhere a template version to do this.

Yes, that's how to do it.

```
template <typename InputIterator>
void moveMessages(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end, uint32_t to_folder_id, int32_t from_folder=-1);
```

> It is possible to do this without templates?

Not really. Different kinds of iterators are different, unrelated types, so you need a template to handle them polymorphically.

> Probably its enogh to receive an "input iterator base class" as a parameter, but how to do this?

There is no base class. In fact, iterators are not necessarily class types at all: pointers can be used as iterators.